# Redirect site alias with php?

Tags: php, redirect, alias

Say I have two domain names:  www.somesite.com and www.anothersite.com and both go to www.somesite.com (anothersite.com is an alias).

Can I, with the index.php on somesite.com, redirect a visitor if they typed in www.anothersite.com (with PHP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

I needed to use HTTP_X_HOST, not HTTP_HOST.

```
<?PHP
if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_HOST']=='anothersite.com'){
    header('Location: http://www.somesite.com/anothersite/');
}
?>
```

Thank you for your answers. :)

Comment: Are you using a proxy then? If so, that probably would have been useful in the question :|

Comment: I really didn't know my situation.  It's one of the reasons I posted to StackOverflow (for guidance).  Sorry.  You've been helpful regardless. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can check against $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']. If it is anothersite.com, redirect using header(). Alternatively, you could use .htaccess with mod_rewrite.

Comment: HTTP_HOST doesn't recognize anothersite.com; it just says somesite.com

Comment: I needed to use http_x_host.  Found a solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depends. If both domains just start the same script, you can check which domain was used. If you redirect (301 or other) from anothersite.com to somesite.com, it becomes a new request, and you cannot see that the user actually typed anothersite.com.

Comment: This may be what's happening.  I've tried HTTP_HOST and all that to no avail.

Comment: Do you think I could reference the script?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (false !== strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], "anothersite.com")){
    header("Location: http://somesite.com");
    die();
}
```

Comment: 1. strpos() can return 0 as the position which will evaluate to false. 2. this won't handle www.anothersite.com and 3. You need an exit; after the header()  call.

Comment: @jasonbar: 1. edited 2. yes it will 3.I do not need to, but it is good point, thanks

Comment: Yerp, you're right. the only thing it would have captured is www.anothersite.com. Without the exit; the rest of page will be executed. Probably not the most desirable situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://www.somesite.com/');
?>
```

-edit-
This only redirects, did not read the question properly.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: That is not an answer to the question at all.

Comment: my bad, didn't read the question completely, feel free to vote down.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?
if(strpos($_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"], 'anothersite.com') !== false) {
  header ("HTTP/1.1 301 Permanent Redirect "); // you don't need that
  header ('Location: http://somewhere.else.com');
  exit();
}


?>
```